# Which GitHub Fine grained access permissions are needed to run brew test-bot --only-formulae?

Tags: git, continuous-integration, github-actions, homebrew

I've got a private homebrew tap repo (from running `brew tap-new`) which accesses another private repo, both on github.

While running the homebrew automation for a PR, it has started to fail.

I changed the `.gitconfig` to use a PAT with access to both the homebrew tap and private repo instead of the default gh-actions token, and tested that `git ls-remote` works.

However, after that, the following fails (when run by `brew test-bot`): `git -C /path/to/homebrew/repo fetch origin +refs/heads/main` which doesn't make sense as the PAT clearly has read access to the `contents` scope of both repos, which seems like it should be the necessary permission to run that command.

Per request base GHA workflow copied into question:

```yaml
# check for updates at: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/dev-cmd/tap-new.rb
name: brew test-bot
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - edited
jobs:
  test-bot:
    runs-on: macos-13
    steps:
      - name: Set up Homebrew
        id: set-up-homebrew
        uses: Homebrew/actions/setup-homebrew@master
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      - name: Cache Homebrew Bundler RubyGems
        id: cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.set-up-homebrew.outputs.gems-path }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-rubygems-${{ steps.set-up-homebrew.outputs.gems-hash }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-rubygems-

      - name: Install Homebrew Bundler RubyGems
        if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: brew install-bundler-gems

      - run: brew test-bot --only-cleanup-before

      - run: brew test-bot --only-setup

      - run: brew test-bot --only-tap-syntax
        env:
          HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      - run: brew test-bot --only-formulae --root-url=https://ghcr.io/v2/getargv/homebrew-tap
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        # env:
        #  HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
        # with env var git fetch of homebrew-tap fails, without env var downloading from private repo fails

      - name: Upload bottles as artifact
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@main
        with:
          name: bottles
          path: '*.bottle.*'

      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.addLabels({
            issue_number: context.issue.number,
            owner: context.repo.owner,
            repo: context.repo.repo,
            labels: ["pr-pull"]
            })
```

and logs from failing step:

```
Run brew test-bot --only-formulae --root-url=https://ghcr.io/v2/getargv/homebrew-tap
  
==> Using Homebrew/homebrew-test-bot 1771ae5 (Merge pull request #958 from Homebrew/artifact_id_string)
==> Using Homebrew/brew 4.1.0-29-gfe7aa4b61 (Merge pull request #15732 from EricFromCanada/create-require-version)
==> Using Homebrew/homebrew-core 61015bd9bce (Merge pull request #133372 from chenrui333/bump-vcpkg-2023.06.08)
==> Testing getargv/homebrew-tap c0b8512 (Merge 2eee8ab807436abc38f103e5aa9885a280bf7e2a into eac896727b99cd4a4d144f75e620850786958524):

==> Running FormulaeDetect#detect_formulae!
==> git -C /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/getargv/homebrew-tap fetch origin +refs/heads/main
    url               https://github.com/getargv/homebrew-tap/pull/4/checks
    tap origin/main eac8967 (only label on PR, run action when PR created or opened not merged)
    HEAD              c0b8512 (Merge 2eee8ab807436abc38f103e5aa9885a280bf7e2a into eac896727b99cd4a4d144f75e620850786958524)
    diff_start_sha1   eac896727b99cd4a4d144f75e620850786958524
    diff_end_sha1     c0b851243d08440221151dce2cee268faf74b1f8

    testing_formulae  getargv/tap/getargv getargv/tap/libgetargv
    added_formulae    (none)
    modified_formulae getargv/tap/getargv getargv/tap/libgetargv
    deleted_formulae  (none)

==> Running Formulae#run!

==> Running Formulae#formula!(getargv/tap/getargv)
==> brew audit --strict --only=gcc_dependency getargv/tap/getargv
==> brew deps --tree --annotate --include-build --include-test getargv/tap/getargv
==> Determining dependencies...
==> brew install --only-dependencies --verbose --build-bottle getargv/tap/getargv
==> Starting tests for getargv/tap/getargv
==> brew fetch --retry getargv/tap/getargv --build-bottle --force
==> FAILED
Full fetch getargv/tap/getargv --build-bottle output
  ==> Fetching getargv from getargv/tap
  Error: Download failed: Environmental variable HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN is required.
==> brew install --verbose --build-bottle getargv/tap/getargv
==> FAILED
Full install --build-bottle getargv/tap/getargv output
Truncated install --build-bottle getargv/tap/getargv output
==> brew audit getargv/tap/getargv --online --git --skip-style
==> FAILED
Full audit getargv/tap/getargv --online --git --skip-style output
==> SKIPPED getargv/tap/getargv


==> Running Formulae#formula!(getargv/tap/libgetargv)
==> brew audit --strict --only=gcc_dependency getargv/tap/libgetargv
==> brew deps --tree --annotate --include-build --include-test getargv/tap/libgetargv
==> Determining dependencies...
==> brew install --only-dependencies --verbose --build-bottle getargv/tap/libgetargv
==> Starting tests for getargv/tap/libgetargv
==> brew fetch --retry getargv/tap/libgetargv --build-bottle --force
==> FAILED
Full fetch getargv/tap/libgetargv --build-bottle output
==> brew install --verbose --build-bottle getargv/tap/libgetargv
==> FAILED
Full install --build-bottle getargv/tap/libgetargv output
Truncated install --build-bottle getargv/tap/libgetargv output
==> brew audit getargv/tap/libgetargv --online --git --skip-style
==> FAILED
Warning: install failed
Full audit getargv/tap/libgetargv --online --git --skip-style output
==> SKIPPED getargv/tap/libgetargv

==> Skipped or failed formulae:
getargv/tap/getargv
getargv/tap/libgetargv
Warning: 2 failed steps ignored!
brew install --verbose --build-bottle getargv/tap/getargv
brew install --verbose --build-bottle getargv/tap/libgetargv
Error: 4 failed steps!
brew fetch --retry getargv/tap/getargv --build-bottle --force
brew audit getargv/tap/getargv --online --git --skip-style
brew fetch --retry getargv/tap/libgetargv --build-bottle --force
brew audit getargv/tap/libgetargv --online --git --skip-style
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

The PAT has:

Repository access:

- getargv/getargv
- getargv/homebrew-tap

Permissions:

- Read access to metadata
- Read and Write access to code and pull requests

By removing the token stuff including the HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN env var the git fetch succeeds but the subsequent attempt to build the formula fails due to lack of access to the private repo.

Here is a file I use to be able to download private repo contents which may be what allows the setup-homebrew step to work.

```rb
# frozen_string_literal: false

require "download_strategy"

module Monkeypatch
  class << self
    def apply_patch
      unless homebrew_version_ok?
        raise "WARNING: It looks like HomeBrew has been upgraded since " \
              "this monkeypatch was writen, please reevaluate the patch in #{__FILE__}."
      end

      const = find_const
      return unless const

      mtd = find_method(const)

      if mtd.nil? || mtd.arity != InstanceMethods.instance_method(:audit_urls).arity
        raise "Could not find class or method when patching " \
              "HomeBrew's audit helper. Please investigate."
      end

      const.prepend(InstanceMethods)
    end

    private

    def find_const
      Kernel.const_get("Homebrew::ResourceAuditor") if Kernel.const_defined?("Homebrew::ResourceAuditor")
    end

    def find_method(const)
      const.instance_method(:audit_urls) if const.method_defined?(:audit_urls)
    end

    def homebrew_version_ok?
      parsed = Version.parse(HOMEBREW_VERSION)
      parsed.major_minor == "4.0"
    end
  end

  module InstanceMethods
    def audit_urls
      if url.match?(%r{github.com/.*/archive/refs/tags})
        strategy = DownloadStrategyDetector.detect(url, using)
        si = strategy.new(url, @name, @version)
        specs.compare_by_identity
        specs["header"] = "Accept: application/vnd.github+json"
        specs["header"] = "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28"
        specs["header"] = "Authorization: Bearer #{Homebrew::EnvConfig.github_api_token}"

        if (http_content_problem = curl_check_http_content(si.download_url,
                                                           "source URL",
                                                           specs:             specs,
                                                           use_homebrew_curl: @use_homebrew_curl))
          problem http_content_problem
        end
      else
        super
      end
    end
  end
end

class GitHubPrivateRepositoryDownloadStrategy < CurlDownloadStrategy
  require "utils/formatter"
  require "utils/github"

  def initialize(url, name, version, **meta)
    super
    parse_url_pattern
    set_github_token
  end

  def parse_url_pattern
    url_pattern = %r{https://github.com/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/\S+/(\S+)\.(?:tar\.gz|zip)}

    unless (match = url.match(url_pattern))
      raise CurlDownloadStrategyError, "Invalid url pattern for GitHub Repository."
    end

    _, @owner, @repo, @version = *match
    @ref = "tags/#{@version}"
  end

  def download_url
    "https://api.github.com/repos/#{@owner}/#{@repo}/tarball/#{@ref}"
  end

  private

  def _fetch(url:, resolved_url:, timeout:)
    curl_download download_url, to: temporary_path, timeout: timeout
  end

  def _curl_args
    [
      "--header", "Accept: application/vnd.github+json",
      "--header", "X-GitHub-Api-Version: 2022-11-28",
      "--header", "Authorization: Bearer #{@github_token}"
    ]
  end

  def set_github_token
    @github_token = ENV.fetch("HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN", nil)

    unless @github_token
      raise CurlDownloadStrategyError, "Environmental variable HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN is required."
    end

    validate_github_repository_access!
  end

  def validate_github_repository_access!
    # Test access to the repository
    GitHub.repository(@owner, @repo)
  rescue GitHub::API::HTTPNotFoundError
    # We switched to GitHub::API::HTTPNotFoundError,
    # because we can now handle bad credentials messages
    message = <<~EOS
      HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN can not access the repository: #{@owner}/#{@repo}
      This token may not have permission to access the repository or the url of formula may be incorrect.
    EOS
    raise CurlDownloadStrategyError, message
  end
end

# GitHubPrivateRepositoryReleaseDownloadStrategy downloads tarballs from GitHub
# Release assets. To use it, add
# `:using => GitHubPrivateRepositoryReleaseDownloadStrategy` to the URL section of
# your formula. This download strategy uses GitHub access tokens (in the
# environment variables HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN) to sign the request.
class GitHubPrivateRepositoryReleaseDownloadStrategy < GitHubPrivateRepositoryDownloadStrategy
  def parse_url_pattern
    url_pattern = %r{https://github.com/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/releases/download/([^/]+)/(\S+)}

    unless (match = @url.match(url_pattern))
      raise CurlDownloadStrategyError, "Invalid url pattern for GitHub Release."
    end

    _, @owner, @repo, @tag, @filename = *match
  end

  def download_url
    "https://api.github.com/repos/#{@owner}/#{@repo}/releases/assets/#{asset_id}"
  end

  private

  def asset_id
    @asset_id ||= resolve_asset_id
  end

  def resolve_asset_id
    release_metadata = fetch_release_metadata
    assets = release_metadata["assets"].select { |a| a["name"] == @filename }

    raise CurlDownloadStrategyError, "Asset file not found." if assets.empty?

    assets.first["id"]
  end

  def fetch_release_metadata
    GitHub.get_release(@owner, @repo, @tag)
  end
end

Monkeypatch.apply_patch
```

Latest error:

```
/usr/bin/env /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/shared/curl --disable --cookie /dev/null --globoff --show-error --user-agent Homebrew/4.1.1-19-gdb86a40\ \(Macintosh\;\ Intel\ Mac\ OS\ X\ 13.4\)\ curl/7.88.1 --header Accept-Language:\ en --retry 3 --location https://api.github.com/graphql --header Accept:\ application/vnd.github\+json --write-out '
'\%\{http_code\} --header Authorization:\ token\ ****** --header X-GitHub-Api-Version:2022-11-28 --data @/private/tmp/github_api_post20230725-8726-1gxr8lc --request POST --dump-header /private/tmp/github_api_headers20230725-8726-1la1q6u
Error: FORBIDDEN: Resource not accessible by personal access token
```

So what do I need to do to get this working again?

Comment: Please include your relevant GHA workflow in your question. Your complete error logs would be helpful too, please include those too. Thanks!

Comment: @Azeem info copied in from linked page

Comment: What kind of permissions `GH_PAT` has? Scopes? Only `contents`?

Comment: @Azeem GH_PAT permissions added to question.

Comment: What do you mean by "access to code"? Contents?

Comment: @Azeem that's how github describes the permission in the summary screen, but yes it's "contents" + "pull requests".

Comment: That's strange. You may try generating a new PAT and test with that. Do you have any branch protection rules?

Comment: No branch protection rules, and I've tried replacing the PAT, didn't work.

Comment: Does this work from your command line on your local machine?

Comment: No idea, I don't use tokens outside CI, as I find ssh way less confusing.

Comment: Right. I did something like this with SSH i.e. updating this [tap](https://github.com/liquidaty/homebrew-zsv) [here](https://github.com/liquidaty/zsv/blob/main/.github/workflows/ci.yml#L322-L331) and here is its corresponding [script](https://github.com/liquidaty/zsv/blob/main/scripts/ci-update-homebrew-tap.sh). Worked great with SSH [deploy keys](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/managing-deploy-keys#deploy-keys). Everything you're doing seems to be fine though but it's not working as expected for you. Not sure why it's not working.

Comment: zsv isn't a private repo, though. So I don't think it's comparable.

Comment: For testing, can you try with a new PAT, a classic one, where you would explicitly grant the "contents" scope?

Comment: @VonC Contents is not a scope available to classic tokens. Perhaps you mean "repo" scope?

Comment: @VonC anyway I get a "remote: Personal access tokens (classic) are forbidden from accessing this repository." error with a classic token.

Comment: And a new non-classic PAT with repo scope does not work either?

Comment: @VonC a new fine grained PAT with contents scope does not work, no. As I said to Azeem. Repo scope is a classic scope.

Answer (score 1):

In case that you still have issues, try this permissions for your token. (I think in my case is passing because it's a dummy test, similar to a hello world, and in your case is a real application which is more complex), try it an let me know.

workflow: read-write

actions: read-write

contents: read-write

pull requests: read-write

Also, by the way, try and do on your side a dummy test too, create 2 repos private, in one put the formulae .rb  and the code in the second repo, upload the tar, so on.  But make it simple

I am wondering if is the PAT permissions or the code do not read the PAT, and if do not read it, it might act like you do not have permissions

**UPDATE2 for GitHub organization account:**

**Solution proposed for attempts to pull image from container registry using fine-grained access token, for Private GitHub Repos**

Fine-grained token permissions:
[image: image here]

however I tested also with this permissions and worked:
[image]

**Workflow is the same I just removed some steps on my end (you do not have too)**

```
# check for updates at: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/dev-cmd/tap-new.rb
name: brew test-bot
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - edited
jobs:
  test-bot:
    runs-on: macos-13
    steps:
      - name: Set up Homebrew
        id: set-up-homebrew
        uses: Homebrew/actions/setup-homebrew@master
        env:
          HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
          debug: true

      - name: Cache Homebrew Bundler RubyGems
        id: cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.set-up-homebrew.outputs.gems-path }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-rubygems-${{ steps.set-up-homebrew.outputs.gems-hash }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-rubygems-

      - name: Install Homebrew Bundler RubyGems
        # if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: brew install-bundler-gems

      - run: brew test-bot --only-cleanup-before

#       - run: brew test-bot --only-setup

#       - run: brew test-bot --only-tap-syntax
#         env:
#           HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
          
      - run: brew update
#       - run: brew test-bot --only-tap-syntax
#         env:
#           HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      - run: |
          git config --global http.extraheader "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n "x-access-token:${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
        env:
          HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      - run: |
          git ls-remote 'https://github.com/KekkeiGenkaiCloud/getargv.git'
          git ls-remote 'https://github.com/KekkeiGenkaiCloud/homebrew-tap.git'

      - name: Run brew test-bot --only-formulae --root-url
        run: brew test-bot --only-formulae --root-url=https://ghcr.io/v2/kekkeigenkaicloud/homebrew-tap
        # if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        env:
          ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG: true
          HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      - name: Upload bottles as an artifact
        # if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: bottles
          path: '*.bottle.*'

      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.addLabels({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              labels: ["pr-pull"]
            })
```

**See pipeline run status**

[image: pipeline status]

**UPDATE2 for personal account:**

**Solution proposed for attempts to pull image from container registry using fine-grained access token**

Fine-grained token permissions:

```
Repository permissions
 Read access to actions, commit statuses, and metadata
 Read and Write access to code and pull requests
```

[Permission selected at token creation see in picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LcMLX.png)

Pipeline ran with success:
[See picture here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GoUUR.png)

**Working solution where TOKEN has all permission selected [however OP do not need all permissions the one necessary for github registry pull]**

I managed to make the pipeline run with success, please keep in mind that is  a dummy testing, I commented some if's since in my case i do not have events. Modify it to align with your needs. Let me know how it worked on your end.

[See here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDraV.png)

TOKEN permissions:
[image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/luR6U.png)

```
# check for updates at: https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/master/Library/Homebrew/dev-cmd/tap-new.rb
name: brew test-bot
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - edited
jobs:
  test-bot:
    runs-on: macos-13
    steps:
      - name: Set up Homebrew
        id: set-up-homebrew
        uses: Homebrew/actions/setup-homebrew@master
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
          debug: true

      - name: Cache Homebrew Bundler RubyGems
        id: cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.set-up-homebrew.outputs.gems-path }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-rubygems-${{ steps.set-up-homebrew.outputs.gems-hash }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-rubygems-

      - name: Install Homebrew Bundler RubyGems
        # if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: brew install-bundler-gems

      - run: brew test-bot --only-cleanup-before

      - run: brew test-bot --only-setup
        env:
          HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
          
      - run: brew update
      - run: brew test-bot --only-tap-syntax
        env:
          HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      - run: |
          git config --global http.extraheader "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n "x-access-token:${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}" | base64 | tr -d '\n')"
        env:
          HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
      - run: |
          git ls-remote 'https://github.com/dummy-andra/getargv.git'
          git ls-remote 'https://github.com/dummy-andra/homebrew-tap.git'
      - name: Run brew test-bot --only-formulae --root-url=
        run: brew test-bot --only-formulae --root-url=https://ghcr.io/v2/dummy-andra/homebrew-tap
        # if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        env:
          ACTIONS_STEP_DEBUG: true
          HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      - name: Upload bottles as an artifact
        # if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v2
        with:
          name: bottles
          path: '*.bottle.*'

      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.addLabels({
              issue_number: context.issue.number,
              owner: context.repo.owner,
              repo: context.repo.repo,
              labels: ["pr-pull"]
            })
```

**This solutions are not applicable for OP issue **
// however this solutions are good if the pipeline fail at http.extraheader step, for OP the pipeline fail at image pull

The PAT has the correct permission, however can you try to edit your workflow file and comment the step that has http.extraheader? Because instead of overriding the extraheader git adds two AUTHORIZATION headers.extra headers to the empty list.

Check this dic: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-httpextraHeader

Let me know how it goes.

Solution 1:

```
name: brew test-bot
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - edited

jobs:
  test-bot:
    runs-on: macos-13
    steps:
      - name: Set up Homebrew
        id: set-up-homebrew
        uses: Homebrew/actions/setup-homebrew@master
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      - name: Cache Homebrew Bundler RubyGems
        id: cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.set-up-homebrew.outputs.gems-path }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-rubygems-${{ steps.set-up-homebrew.outputs.gems-hash }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-rubygems-

      - name: Install Homebrew Bundler RubyGems
        if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: brew install-bundler-gems

      # Remove this step to avoid interfering with token usage
      # - run: 'git config --replace-all "http.extraheader" "Authorization: Basic $(echo -n "x-access-token:$HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN" | base64 | tr -d ''\n'')"'
      #   env:
      #     HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      # Instead of using 'git ls-remote', use Homebrew 'brew update' to fetch the latest changes
      - run: brew update

      # (Optional) If you need to verify the existence of specific branches, you can use 'git ls-remote' here
      # - run: git ls-remote 'https://github.com/getargv/getargv.git'
      # - run: git ls-remote 'https://github.com/getargv/homebrew-tap.git'

      - run: brew test-bot --only-formulae --root-url=https://ghcr.io/v2/getargv/homebrew-tap
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        env:
          HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      - name: Upload bottles as artifact
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@main
        with:
          name: bottles
          path: '*.bottle.*'

      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.addLabels({
            issue_number: context.issue.number,
            owner: context.repo.owner,
            repo: context.repo.repo,
            labels: ["pr-pull"]
            })
```

Solution 2: Reset the Extraheader List with Git Commands

The second solution involves using Git commands within the workflow to reset the extraheader list and avoid the duplicate AUTHORIZATION headers.

```
name: brew test-bot
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
      - edited

jobs:
  test-bot:
    runs-on: macos-13
    steps:
      - name: Set up Homebrew
        id: set-up-homebrew
        uses: Homebrew/actions/setup-homebrew@master
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      - name: Cache Homebrew Bundler RubyGems
        id: cache
        uses: actions/cache@v3
        with:
          path: ${{ steps.set-up-homebrew.outputs.gems-path }}
          key: ${{ runner.os }}-rubygems-${{ steps.set-up-homebrew.outputs.gems-hash }}
          restore-keys: ${{ runner.os }}-rubygems-

      - name: Install Homebrew Bundler RubyGems
        if: steps.cache.outputs.cache-hit != 'true'
        run: brew install-bundler-gems

      # Reset the extraheader list using Git commands
      - name: Reset Git Extraheader
        run: |
          GIT_TRACE=1 GIT_TRANSFER_TRACE=1 GIT_CURL_VERBOSE=1 git \
            -c "http.https://github.com/.extraheader=" \
            -c "http.https://github.com/.extraheader=AUTHORIZATION: basic ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}" \
            push https://github.com/owner/my-repo.git

      # Instead of using 'git ls-remote', use Homebrew 'brew update' to fetch the latest changes
      - run: brew update

      # (Optional) If you need to verify the existence of specific branches, you can use 'git ls-remote' here
      # - run: git ls-remote 'https://github.com/getargv/getargv.git'
      # - run: git ls-remote 'https://github.com/getargv/homebrew-tap.git'

      - run: brew test-bot --only-formulae --root-url=https://ghcr.io/v2/getargv/homebrew-tap
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        env:
          HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

      - name: Upload bottles as artifact
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@main
        with:
          name: bottles
          path: '*.bottle.*'

      - uses: actions/github-script@v6
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        with:
          script: |
            github.rest.issues.addLabels({
            issue_number: context.issue.number,
            owner: context.repo.owner,
            repo: context.repo.repo,
            labels: ["pr-pull"]
            })
```

Comment: Neither approach worked. The first approach didn't change the errors at all. The second approach failed with a 400 error.

Comment: Apologies for the inconvenience caused by the previous solutions that didn't work as expected, I will continue to address the issue on my end to find a suitable solution. Before proceeding, may I kindly inquire if you have attempted using a traditional (classical) token with full permissions, and if so, encountered similar challenges? Fine-grained personal access tokens  are currently in beta.
I will circle back once I finish my dummy test ;)

Comment: I tried a classic token and got a "remote: Personal access tokens (classic) are forbidden from accessing this repository." error.

Comment: By the way for solution too I had a typo: 
      - run: brew test-bot --only-formulae --root-url=https://ghcr.io/v2/getargv/homebrew-tap
        if: github.event_name == 'pull_request'
        env:
          GH_PAT: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

is  HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}

Comment: Now the pipeline is still runnning, it takes ages to run :( 
I will be back

Comment: Running this latest workflow with my repo name subbed in, I get Error: FORBIDDEN: Resource not accessible by personal access token. I see that you seem to have added every single permission to your PAT? any idea which ones are actually needed? I highly doubt for example that codespaces is needed.

Comment: Indeed I added all, I will look into it today, yesterday was almost 23pm and I was sleepy. For a normal classical token there is an option called package that once selected gives access to github registry, I will look what is the equivalent for fine-grained. I assume that for fine-grained is contest one, I will test it

Comment: Unfortunately I can not extend this discussion to chat since I do not have enough reputation. 
I tested on my end, and it worked to pull the image with the fine-grained token.
Repository permissions
 Read access to actions, commit statuses, and metadata
 Read and Write access to code and pull requests
I also updated the Answer, take a look there to see what I have selected.
Please keep me updated, and let me know how it works on your end

By the way I am a user on github, I do not use an organization, however I do not think it's affecting

Comment: I've awarded the bounty to you since you got this working on your end and the window to do so was almost up. I've matched the fine-grained permissions that you used and it still doesn't work on my end but at this point I think my github org must have some kind of permissions bug.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I appreciate it. Now it's 22:00pm for me, I will try tomorrow morning on my end in an organisation. Since I am curious what happens. Also from ghithub registry documentation is saying that fine-grained tokens are not accepted,  but on my tests were,  the documentation possible is not updated. Also fine-grained tokens are in beta, it's possible not to act as desired. I will test again tomorrow and let you know. By the way in your case if you create a grained PAT with full access is still not working? Is your repo private? In my case the repo where I run the pipeline is public,

Comment: So the repo where I have the pipeline is public, and the gvargs and brew-tap are private. I wanted all to be private, however if I set the repo where I run the pipeline private, the first task Homebrew-setup fails... so I put it public to test the registry.  In all case all repos are private no? How do you managed to make hombrew-setup task work?

Comment: :( oh I do not deserve the bounty :((. No worries I will test it until I will figure this out. I will update you

Comment: My purpose is to deliver a suitable solution whith or without a reward 

Comment: All of the repos involved in my setup are private, yes. For the homebrew-setup step it may be succeeding due to a patch I make to homebrew (I didn't realize that step doesn't like private repos, as that step always worked for me). I'll post the patch in the question.

Comment: I created my own Organization(free). I used a dummy .rb app and a  custom-download.rb patch simular with yours.

I edited a bit the workflow, I removed some steps (curl was failing) and I did not found them necessary for testing the image pull.

I created the fine-grained Tocken with Repo access and ORG access

The pipeline passed with success.  

See in answer the new update

Comment: I'm a little busy atm so I don't have a lot of time to do testing but I copied the permissions that you used and got an error when curl tries to talk to the graphql API. I'd try and gather more info but like i said i'm sort of busy with work. I don't mind putting this on pause until I have more time for helping from my end.

Comment: Hey i think it has something to do with it running against a PR, it seems to do some extra checking when that is the case. In your testing is your workflow running in a PR context?

Comment: Yes, I created a free organisation and 2 private repository, and I used your plugin. However I used a dummy code for formula.  I see in your case that it fails when it tries to communicate with the getargv repo. In homebrew-tap you have the getargv.rb and libgetargv.rb Formulas and in getargv repo you have the code no? Is there any example of code that I can use and test again?

Comment: For you it fails even if you create a token and give full repo and org access? You can delete the token after that, however doing this test at least we can eliminate the token permission issue, and look either to the code, either to the repo...

Comment: according to to https://docs.github.com/en/rest/packages/packages?apiVersion=2022-11-28#about-github-packages: "To use the REST API to manage GitHub Packages, you must authenticate using a personal access token (classic)." so feel free to change your answer to say what I wanted to do is impossible.

Comment: interesting, I saw the documentation but I thought was not updated since in my case din not failed, however I suspect that my formulae was not seen as a package or something like that, not sure, I will try to repro on my end, I want to get the same result :).  By the way my organization when I created it I allowed to use fine-grained tokens and also classical ones, I did not applied any restriction, but for the tests i used PR and fine grained token, I am intrigued. Sorry for not sharing the documentation with you from the start, as I said I got mislead by my results :(

Answer (score -1):

You're running into an issue with HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN not being recognized in your Homebrew test-bot GitHub Actions workflow. This issue arises from the fact that you have commented out the part of the GitHub Actions workflow where HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN is declared in the environment:

```yaml
# env:
#  HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
```

The first action I recommend you take is to uncomment this part of the workflow:

```yaml
env:
  HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GH_PAT }}
```

You should then attempt to run the workflow again.

If you're still encountering issues it could be that your token doesn't have the correct permissions. In order for your workflow to function as expected, your token should have the following permissions:

repo: This grants full control of private repositories, which includes repo:status, repo_deployment, public_repo, security_events, and read:packages.
workflow: This grants the ability to update GitHub Actions workflow runs.
Ensure your PAT has these permissions and, if it doesn't, update it accordingly.

Even after setting up the PAT with the correct permissions and uncommenting HOMEBREW_GITHUB_API_TOKEN in your workflow, you might still face issues. If that is the case, it would be beneficial to generate a new token.

Comment: I have tried all of that, as documented in the comments and question.